# Optional objects spring boot - get object fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, crud

I have defined customer entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and CrudRepository

```
public interface CustomerRepo extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

if I use CustomerRepo.findById method for finding Customer

```
@Autowired
CustomerRepo repo;

Optional<Customer> dbCustomer = repo.findById(id);
```

how can I get name of that customer. I cannot use getter then.
so I'm interested is there any solution of using getters of Optional, or I need to use other method for finding Customer by id?

Comment: Add a method in the repo for finding customer by id, and then you can use like this `Customer dbCustomer = repo.findById(id);`

Comment: I tried and getting "Incompatible types. Required: com.fitnet.phonqpon.models.Customer Found: java.util.Optional <com.fitnet.phonqpon.models.Customer>"........
but if I add  Customer findById (Long id); method inside of CustomerRepo interface I am getting "'findById(Long)' in 'com.fitnet.phonqpon.repositories.CustomerRepo' clashes with 'findById(ID)' in 'org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository'; attempting to use incompatible return type"

Comment: You can change the field name of your primary key to customerId or something and add a method in repo like `findByCustomerId(Long id)`

Comment: id is field name of my primary key

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Optional<Customer>` is returned, because it is not guaranteed that there will be such a customer with the requested ID in the database.
Instead of returning null it simply means that `Optional.isPresent()` will return false when the ID does not exist.

According to the API Docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-):

```
Returns:
the entity with the given id or Optional#empty() if none found
```

You will therefore probably want to simply use the methods on `Optional` to check whether it contains a Customer (i.e. a Customer with that ID exists), and then get the name like so:

```
Optional<Customer> dbCustomer = repo.findById(id);
if(dbCustomer.isPresent()) {
    Customer existingCustomer = dbCustomer.get();
    String nameWeWanted = existingCustomer.getName();
    //operate on existingCustomer
} else {
    //there is no Customer in the repo with 'id'
}
```

Alternatively you can try callback style (shown with Java 8 Lambda):

```
Optional<Customer> dbCustomer = repo.findById(id);
dbCustomer.ifPresent(existingCustomer -> {
    String nameWeWanted = existingCustomer.getName();
    //operate on existingCustomer
});
```

It is worth noting that it is possible to check existence of the ID without actually retrieving/loading the entity by using the interface method:

```
boolean CrudRepository.existsById(ID id)
```

This saves an entity load, but it still requires a database roundtrip.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. That helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use another method for finding Customer:

```
@Autowired
CustomerRepo repo;

Customer dbCustomer = repo.findOne(id);
```